# debug log filter only for one user

Tags: debugging, logging

The account I am using is Secondary Admin.

And in Debug Logs, I am getting other user's log [using Salesforce UI]. It is quite annoying as it makes me hard to find my own debug logs.

For Monitored Users, I only add the user name that I am using. Means only one user is showing under Monitored Users.

But in Debug Logs section, it shows another user's log also.

In the view, I tried to filter by the user name with I am using. But still able to see another person logs.

I just experienced this about 3 days ago.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is this within the Salesforce UI, or the Developer Console?

Comment: It is in Salesforce UI. As I don't use developer console to view the logs, I am not sure about that. If I see the same issue in developer console, I will update my question.